# how to select particular product from bunch of products

Tags: commerce

I have two fields in my content type. one field(seat) has more than 10 products( product reference ) and another field (default). while selecting one product in the seated field ,should be shown in the default field. I do not know how to get that product from seat to default. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to react on a node save, check if the field has only one value and alter the values of the node as needed.

Or you can write your own module and use the [form_set_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_value/7) function to change the submitted values in a (custom) validation function. Your validation function can be attached to the node edit form by implementing [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and adding the function to the `$form['#validate']` array.